# Smoother transition from fullscreen activity using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I'm developing an **Android application which uses `ActionBarSherlock` (*ABS*) and needs to work in API >=8**. The problem is that **some transitions between activities aren't smooth enough**.

**For example**: I have two activities, (A) one which is always fullscreen and (B) another one which isn't fullscreen (*status bar* and *action bar* are shown). The transition needed is always from A to B. When it occurs and B activity is loaded, all the content (included ABS) is shown as if the activity was fullscreen and then resizes when the *status bar* is loaded again. 
In some devices this effect is insignificant but in other ones it becomes really annoying and even causes that the user touches the wrong section of the view.

**Fullscreen declaration is made via Manifest** activity's "theme" property (anything by code). For example:

```
<activity
    android:name = "...."
    android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
    android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Searching on the Internet for some solution, **I've found two main approaches**:

1) ***To use the Android appcompat library and enabling action bar overlay*** as mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html#EnableOverlay.
The problem with this is that the app also uses the *HoloEverywhere* library and many errors appeared when using *HoloEverywhere* + *appcompat*. All this errors were related to duplicated XML elements. I've also checked *android-support-v4* library in all projects to avoid errors.

2) ***Using `WindowManager` flags and applying top padding to the view***: http://nubinewsblog.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/smooth-full-screen-transition.html.
With this approach the transition is perfect. The biggest problem - and the reason I need to ask this - is that I'm not able to apply a top margin to *ABS* and the status bar is shown over the action bar. I can move down all elements except *ABS*. I suppose it occurs because *ABS* uses many fixed dimensions and attributes.

I prefer to use the second way (2) but I can try everything needed to make the transition smoother. Any further implementation details needed can be asked and I'll try to answer ASAP. I'd be very grateful for any info or help provided :-)

**Really thanks to all for your time**.

PS: I'm currently using and **Android 2.3.6 device for testing**.

PS: **when I say fullscreen I always refer to fullscreen + no status bar + no action bar**.

Comment: isn't it jumpy because of the notification bar?

Comment: I'm really sorry for answering so late. Yes, the problem is the notification bar. When it appears, all the content is resized and this produces the jumpy transition. The problem is that I'm not able to make this transition smoother.

Comment: oh, so you have a similar (or the same) problem as i've asked about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731429/smooth-transition-between-full-screen-activity-and-one-with-notification-bar-and

Comment: Exactly :-) I have the same problem as you mentioned. I've tried too much solutions so far but with no success. Please, if you managed to solve this problem, I'd be very grateful if you could notify me. In the same way, If I solve it, I would notify you. Really thanks for your time ;)

Comment: ok. can you please tell me how do i get all of the comments i've written on SO , so that i could return to this post?

Comment: That's an interesting question :-) I'm not sure if it exists the option to see all the posts in which you've commented. To achieve that, I think you can:

Comment: (I continue here as I'm not able to edit the previous comment)
1.- Add this post to your favourites (click on the star near the post title)
2.- Check your questions & answers through the Inbox section (it's in the upper side of the web page, near the StackExchange sites logo)
3.- Accessing your favourites and activity section. You can access them by clicking in the upper side near the "help" section. Here you will see your current points and image. If you click here you will access your private section

Comment: Also (4) if you enter in your own post you will see in the right side a section called "Linked". Here this post should appear to you :-) I'm sorry for not being able to provide more help.

Comment: such a basic feature doesn't exist? too bad. since i don't handle the question's presented problem anymore, i don't think i will be able to help you (at least not in the near future). sorry. i wonder if it occurs even on newer android devices, and without any support library.

Comment: I have a new testing device. It's a Samsung Galaxy ACE 2 NFC with Android 4.1.2. In this case, I can confirm you that this problem doesn't occur. I think this issue is related only with some Android versions. In the case of the Galaxy ACE 2 the transition is smooth because all the GUI elements appear at the same time and they doesn't resize or move when the notification bar appears. I'm sorry, I forgot to mention this detail before ;-)

Comment: well i have Galaxy S3 with 4.3 (and also had it with 4.1 before), and it didn't have this issue. it's weird that i've seen it happening on other devices (i think it was even a nexus 4) .

Comment: I've tested it in other device (Samsung Galaxy S2, Android 2.3) and this issue happens. I think it's related with older Android version (but I'm still not sure). I'll continue investigating. If this only occurs in older versions I won't care too much of this problem as the number of users with this Android versions is continuously decreasing :-) In spite of this, I'll try to find a solution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've **solved my problem doing** the following:

1.- I have to **optimize all the screens** where the AB was shown. In some cases I used ListViews which weren't correctly implemented and that caused a noticeable load time in the activity.

2.- I have **shown the status bar BEFORE starting the new activity**. I mean: I've shown the status bar in the fullscreen activity just before starting the non-fullscreen one. With that I achieved that the layout of the second activity (non-fullscreen) was never resized.

With this two little changes now the AB transition is much more smoother.

I close this question but, if someone has any doubt, I will be pleased to answer it. Last but not least, ¡thanks to all who tried to help with this problem!

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to clear full screen flags on onPause method of first (full screen) activity

```
 @Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation and code to your answer