# Smooth transition between full-screen-activity and one with notification-bar and action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-notification-bar, android-fullscreen

### Background

I have an app that has 2 activities :

- splash activity, which is shown in full screen (no action bar, no notification bar)
- main activity, which has both an action bar (uses actionBarSherlock) and a notification bar.

### The problem

For some reason, when going from the first activity to the second, there is a "jumpy" layout process, which shows the content of the second activity without the action bar and notification bar, and a moment later it shows them both.

This causes the content below to move too, which is very noticeable.

### Possible solution

As I've seen, a possible solution would be to hide the action bar and show it a bit later (500ms later), but this seems like a bad solution (making it slower and hiding for no reason), plus I need to get the actionBar items positions for another purpose (for showing a tutorial).

### The question

Is it possible to avoid the "jumpiness"? One that doesn't involve such a weird workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I've **solved my problem doing** the following:

1.- I have to **optimize all the screens** where the AB was shown. In some cases I used ListViews which weren't correctly implemented and that caused a noticeable load time in the activity.

2.- I have **shown the status bar BEFORE starting the new activity**. I mean: I've shown the status bar in the fullscreen activity just before starting the non-fullscreen one. With that I achieved that the layout of the second activity (non-fullscreen) was never resized.

With this two little changes now the AB transition is much more smoother.

You can find the complete post with my answer at: [Smoother transition from fullscreen activity using ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238216/smoother-transition-from-fullscreen-activity-using-actionbarsherlock)

Comment: Thank you. I hope I will remember to use this tip when I see this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some other animation slide transitions rather than default popping one?

something like this?

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.accelerate_interpolator, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Here is the Animation lists that you can use
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html

Comment: i'm not talking about the transition animation at all. i'm talking about the notification bar that comes and moves everything a little to the bottom, after the content itself is shown, and this is not in an animation but a very "jumpy" experience.